# Environment variable cannot be seen in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using following commands to build environment  with `docker-compose.sh`:

```
curl -L --fail https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.23.0/run.sh -o docker-compose.sh
chmod +x docker-compose.sh
export DOCKER_CONTAINER_POSTFIX="test_name"

./docker-compose.sh  -p $PROJECT_NAME  build --compress
./docker-compose.sh -p $PROJECT_NAME  up --exit-code-from runner runner
./docker-compose.sh -p $PROJECT_NAME down
```

With the following docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2.3'

services:
  base:
    image: base
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

  pytest_worker_01:
    extends:
      service: base
    container_name: "worker_${DOCKER_CONTAINER_POSTFIX}"

  runner:
    extends:
      service: base
    container_name: "runner_${DOCKER_CONTAINER_POSTFIX}"
    depends_on:
      - worker
    networks:
      - default
    command: ["cmd"]
```

The issue that `DOCKER_CONTAINER_POSTFIX` isn't available during building and starting new services. Also, I've tried to use commands like:

```
DOCKER_CONTAINER_POSTFIX="test_name" ./docker-compose.sh  -p $PROJECT_NAME  build --compress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The downloaded script `docker-compose.sh` performs own routine, if you take a closer look in it you will see that it's running `exec docker run ...` command below:

```
exec docker run --rm $DOCKER_RUN_OPTIONS $DOCKER_ADDR $COMPOSE_OPTIONS $VOLUMES -w "$(pwd)" $IMAGE "$@"
```

The key here is passing `COMPOSE_OPTIONS` variable, which is right point of injecting things like env variables. Replacing export of `DOCKER_CONTAINER_POSTFIX` to another one will address your issue:

```
COMPOSE_OPTIONS = "-e DOCKER_CONTAINER_POSTFIX=test_name"
```